# tools:replace="android:icon doesn't work

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I use :

1. **Android Studio 2.2.2**
2. **Compile SDK version : API 23**
3. **Build Tool Version 23.0.2**

I'm trying to use [SweetAlert for Android](https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog) library for dialogs in my android application

so after i add  `compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'` to my dependencies i got this error

> Attribute application@icon value=(@mipmap/launcher) from
>   AndroidManifest.xml:19:9-40   is also present at
>   [com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-45
>   value=(@drawable/ic_launcher).    Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:icon"' to  element at
>   AndroidManifest.xml:16:5-56:19 to override.

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<application
    android:name=".utils.MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Red"
    tools:replace="android:icon">
```

Comment: Are you use xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" ?

Comment: yes i added it : xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

Answer (score 5):

Add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in the manifest tag at your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Notice the **http://** before **schemas**.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.your.app">
```

Comment: ```Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:resource"'```